# Is it possible to override Excel 2007's right click functionality and replace it with a custom menu?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm working on a forecasting spreadsheet and I'd like it to make it as easy as possible for my forecasters to edit the forecast.  I'm hoping to develop some custom VB that will allow the user to highlight a group of cells (in one particular row) and then right-click to display a menu that includes various methods of adjusting the highlighted cells:

1. increase by 10%
2. add 2 to each highlighted cell
3. spread an inputted value evenly to highlighted cells
4. and others

Questions:

1. How do I override Excel's right click functionality so that when my forecasters right click, they get the forecast adjuster menu form instead of Excel standard formatting menu.
2. Can anyone point me in the direction of a cell adjuster similar to what I am describing.

Thanks for you assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to edit my right click menu:

[MenuRighter](http://yoursumbuddy.com/menurighter/)

Note: I did not write this, all credit to @Doug Glancy